# Elementary proof of a generalized Triangle Inequality

Tags: inequality, triangle-inequality

My teacher gave this lemma in class without proof, I tried to prove it but found it seemed a little bit tricky:

Let a, b,  c be real numbers. Then for any
$ \varepsilon\in(0, 1)$ we have $|\left| a-c\right|^{2}-|b-c|^{2}|\leq \frac{12}{\varepsilon} | a-b|^{2}+2 \varepsilon |a-c|^{2}$.

I found the original paper of this lemma(in page 39 of [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/s13218-017-0519-3), and it refers to [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1137/1.9781611973075.50)), but it uses very complicated tools. Is there any elementary proof?

Comment: For example you can set $a=(-1,0), b=(1,0), c=(x,y)$ and evaluate RHS-LHS.

Comment: My first try, which might fail, would be to let $r = (a-b), ~s = (b-c) \implies (r + s) = (a-c).$  Per the assertion, the actual values of $a,b,c$ are **totally irrelevant**.  The only thing that counts are the values of $r$ and $s$.  Consider the assertion $$|(r+s)^2 - s^2| ~~~?\leq ? ~~~\left[\frac{12}{\epsilon} \times r^2 \right] + \left[2\epsilon \times (r + s)^2 \right].$$  Dispensing with **any attempt at elegance** (if necessary), there are not that many cases to explore, re whether (for example) $(r + s)$ is positive, negative, or zero. ...see next comment

Comment: Note that in general, $$(r - s)^2 \geq 0 \implies (r^2 + s^2) \geq 2rs.$$Your posting has a number of defects that prevent MathSE reviewers from handing you an answer, until these defects are repaired.  See [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) 
 for details.

Comment: Is $12/\epsilon$ supposed to be $1/(2\epsilon)$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Nice telepathy.